# Ubercart for 'serious' eCommerce?

Tags: ecommerce, drupal

I'm big Drupal fan, and some very high profile sites use Drupal which also suggests that its a good system. Can the same be said for Ubercart?

I've used it for some small eCommerce sites purely because I know Drupal. It seems to lack some basic features and also relies on JavaScript. I don't know of any high profile eCommerce sites using it.

My productivity would take a big hit if I had to learn a new eCommerce platform and also if I couldn't use my favorite CMS with it, but do I have a choice? If not I guess I can hope that Drupal 7's Commerce module will be an improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"High profile" is quite a subjective thing. These sites are using it: http://www.ubercart.org/site

32,000 sites are reported as using it http://drupal.org/project/usage/ubercart but I appreciate this is not the same thing as a few well known sites using it.

Comment: To be honest, I'm looking for a subjective answerer! I had a look at that link, I don't recognize any of the names but I don't think their organized in order of size.

Comment: I guess if you don't recognise them then they aren't high profile to you! I didn't recognise any on the first page, but there are several to go through.

Comment: If their not in order of size or recognizably then the list is a bit meaningless for this. If you randomly looked at Drupal sites it would probably be a very long time before you saw one you recognized.